# Where i should hash user password, in web-server application or in database? (pros&cons)

Tags: java, database, oracle, security, hash

I'm trying to create a website, that has a functionality to register users with Oracle as database and JavaEE+Tomcat as server application.
I read about different techniques and recommendations about hashing passwords and salting them with unique salt per user.
I discovered that there are tools both in Java and Oracle to do this:
1) Oracle: https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/storing-passwords-in-the-database-9i
2) Java: http://howtodoinjava.com/security/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/

So i can solve this problem in two ways:

1) Hash password in web application and send to database hash-value via JDBC connection;
2) Send password as plain text to database and perform hashing inside it by using Oracle DBMS_CRYPTO package.

I've already tried to search for this topic but all i've found is questions about client-side hashing with JavaScript vs server-side hashing without accent on database vs web-application part.

Maybe there is no exact answer, so, tell me please:
what advantages and disadvantages these solutions have? What problems i can face by using first or second one?

Comment: I'm not sure what the currently recommended hashing algorithm is, but you should avoid MD5 since it has been broken for years. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/why-do-people-still-use-recommend-md5-if-it-is-cracked-since-1996

Comment: Problem with option 2 unless database connection between tomcat and DB server is encrypted. Potential issue with option 2, by locking into Oracle implementation, making potential move to other DBMS vendor difficult. Option 1 allows more freedom in selecting salt-generator and hashing algorithms. So I'd go with option 1, assuming you select algorithm of appropriate strength, like @BooRadley told you.

Comment: If you hash the password in the client don't even bother with security, there is none.

Comment: You can implement the hash algorithm in Java and then load it into Oracle as a stored function/procedure using the `loadjava` utility or `CREATE JAVA SOURCE` if you are worried about being tied into Oracle.

Comment: Just hashing the password, even with a salt is not sufficient to be secure, there needs to be a time/cpu consuming element such as iteration.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a https connection.
2. Send the password as entered.
3. On registration hash (details follow) the password and save in DB
4. On login hash the password and compare to hashed value I'm the DB.

How to hash:
Do not encrypt password. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration (the salt needs to be saved with the hash). Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Depending the hashing method from above either the salt, iteration and version is saved with the hashed password or this will need to be done in your code.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.